# Unable to RDP to Windows Server 2012 via VPN connection

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012, rdp

Using a VPN connection I am able to RDP to all of my servers other than the Windows 2012 servers.  When on the local network I was successfully able to connect to them.

I saw a post that seemed to fit my situation completely but that indicated that an individual needed to change a setting in his Windows 7 Remote Desktop Connection to 'Connect and don't warn me'.  Mine was already set to that.

I also saw posts that appeared to indicate that there may be a role that needed to be set on the Windows 2012 server.  Is that correct?  If so, could you please give directions so that I could pass them to my server person.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's not much to go on here.  What error(s) are you getting?  Can you ping the server in question by name and/or IP when on the VPN?  Does your client IP when on the VPN reside on a network that can see this server (again ping test)?

Comment: Also, I'm assuming you are stating you VPN in and then try to RDP to it?  If that's the case, you should change the title to "Unable to RDP to Windows Server 2012 while on VPN"

Comment: Are you able to ping the Win2012 servers from your system on the VPN?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and just figured it out. I was able to login to the 2012 server when using RDP from with the network but when using F5 VPN I was able to login to VPN and reach the landing page but unable to rdp into the server. Fix: I logged into the 2012 server, clicked the window in the lower right corner, right clicked "This PC" and then clicked properties. I then clicked remote settings and unchecked the box for "Allow remote connections only from computers running remote desktop with Network Level Authentication"

I am now able to connect to the server through VPN.

Answer (score -2):

If you have direct access to your Windows Server 2012 machine, check if Remote Desktop is enabled under System Properties. Remote Desktop access may also be disabled with a group policy, so consult your domain administrator on what policy was applied across the Windows Server 2012 machines.

Comment: He says it works locally.